# How can I get rid of an on-hold designation?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I asked two questions in *Mathematica* SE. Both of my questions have been put on hold as off-topic. How can I get rid of them or do I need to wait (if yes, how long)?

Also, I have modified one of the questions after receiving suggestions to edit it, but it seems to stay in the on-hold status.

I would like help in obeying the site guidelines, so I can post relevant questions in future.

Comment: Hello hbaromega. You do not need to consider being put on hold, or in general that your question is closed, as a signal that your question was bad. If people think your question is bad, for example because it lacks effort, people will downvote and or say so in the comments. Your second question was fine in my opinion, but on this site we still close such questions, as they are unlikely to help other users. It is also nice mark a question as closed, so that you can quickly see that no more effort is required by answerers.

Comment: In my opinion, it is best to close a question that can be found in the docs only after it has been answered. I hope the answers helped you. It seems you changed your second question in order to try to get rid of the "on hold" status, but in doing so you changed the question considerably. If you have a new question, it is probably better to post a new question, rather to edit an old one. Otherwise, answers may refer to outdated facts. Of course I understand you didn't do so if you felt your questions were not appreciated. I must also say I am guilty of having made a mess in this way myself.

Comment: By "How can I get rid of them", do you mean get the questions re-opened or do mean delete the question themselves? It is not clear what "them" refers to.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob. So what should I do now? Leave it as it is? I cannot delete it anymore since the question was answered by other members. 

Also now if I want to make a new post (hopefully a 'good' one), I see a warning saying: *Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more* 

That scares me! No clue what should be my action now!

Comment: @m_goldberg, hope it is now clear to you. I don't want to have questions with "on hold" status. Better they get deleted.

Comment: @hbaromega Ah that is unfortunate about the warning message. On the rest of stackexchange it seems like closing questions is done with different motivation. For example, on the math stackexchange, much less questions are closed. So it makes sense that the system keeps track of some kind of score of quality of questions and penalises you for closed questions. But again, on this SE sub site, if you question is closed it is not necessarily a bad thing. Also, to quote Verbeia, one of our moderators: "the decision to suspend rests with human moderators". So you will not automatically be banned.

Comment: See also [this](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1304/4330) Q&A. Moving forward, I hope you can accept that you asked these two questions which could have been answer by looking closely at the docs. So I hope you are not ashamed or anything, and that you do not wish them to be deleted. I myself misinterpreted the docs countless times and it is good to interact with someone to see what you are missing. I'd suggest you do nothing about the first question and you return the second question to it's original state. And ignore the warning message when asking new questions :).

Comment: *Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more*  <--- this is news to me, and I think it's also news to several other high-rep members.  It's a problem that we don't know what the site presents to new users.

Comment: @Szabolcs Do we know (at least) if that is the result of having a record of _closed_ or _deleted_ questions? If "the system" is against new users with a few closed questions we should rethink our "standards"